# Embedded Jetty - Disable URL rewriting for external URLs

Tags: url-rewriting, jetty, embedded-jetty, http-redirect, jsessionid

I'm using Jetty, in an embedded server configuration. When the client is not accepting cookies, Jetty uses URL rewriting to encode the session ID in the URL itself (adding something like `;jsessionid=xxx` to the URL).

My problem is that when I redirect the client (using a *HTTP 302, moved temporarily*) to an external URL, this URL rewriting breaks the external URL I redirect to (ie, `;jsessionid=xxx` is also present in the URL).

How can I selectively disable URL rewriting on embedded Jetty for external URL? Is this a bug of Jetty? I'm using Jetty 9.4.7. I also tried to set the option `org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.SessionDomain`, but with no avail.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the answer by digging into the Jetty code path. You just need to enable the following init option:

```
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.CheckingRemoteSessionIdEncoding=true
```

For example for embedded Jetty:

```
ServletContextHandler context = ...
context.setInitParameter(
    "org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.CheckingRemoteSessionIdEncoding",
    "true");
```

*Note for the interested reader*: The code related to this is in `org.eclipse.jetty.server.Response::encodeURL()` (line 477 for v9.4.7).